# crossfilter: how to extract time information from start date and end date columns

Tags: crossfilter

I have a list of projects with their start date and end date in separate columns.
I want to show how many projects are in each month on a bar graph.
Each project is required to be counted on each month between start and end month so that I can see how many projects are still active in each month. Data looks like below.

Projects,Start Date,End Date
Project 1,6/10/2013,5/31/2014
Project 2,6/13/2013,2/14/2014
Project 3,6/16/2013,6/15/2014
Project 4,6/20/2013,3/31/2014
Project 5,6/21/2013,3/20/2014
Project 6,6/21/2013,3/31/2014
Project 7,7/1/2013,1/1/2014
Project 8,7/1/2013,3/30/2014
Project 9,7/1/2013,6/30/2014
Project 10,7/1/2013,12/31/2014
Project 11,7/15/2013,1/15/2014
Project 12,7/16/2013,3/31/2014
Project 13,8/15/2013,2/15/2014
Project 14,8/27/2013,3/31/2014
Project 15,9/1/2013,10/31/2014
Project 16,9/2/2013,2/28/2014
Project 17,9/2/2013,12/31/2014
Project 18,9/7/2013,12/31/2014
Project 19,9/10/2013,3/9/2014
Project 20,9/13/2013,3/31/2014
Project 21,10/1/2013,3/31/2014

in excel I prepare data for graph as below (for year 2014)
Jan,    12
Feb,    11
Mar,    9
Apr,    4
May,    4
Jun,    4
Jul,    4
Aug,    4
Sep,    4
Oct,    4
Nov,    3
Dec,    3

(As I am newbie in Stackoverflow, I cannot post sample graph but anyway I hope you can see what I want from the data prepared for the graph.) How to do that with crossfilter.js?

Regards
KNW

Comment: Hello, how did you manage to do that? I have a similar situation,, I hope if you can help me?

Comment: Since it's a common crossfilter question, I added an example to dc.js using an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). Details are in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35322239/676195

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this is exactly how I wanted to do the graph!